# How to lookup a value and return multiple unique values (remove duplicates) to a single cell - comma separated

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup, concatenation, array

I am trying to take a value (unique id) from column AC, do a lookup in column (B) and return (meaning concatenate) the multiple **unique** values from an adjacent column (C) to a single cell in column AD. I only want to return the unique values, eliminating the duplicates, and have all the results returned in a single cell, comma separated. Please see example below. There are approximately 800 unique IDs to lookup and approximately 5000 rows of data. I am open to a formula, array or VBA solution. Thanks.

```
    Source Data:
    Column B     Column C   ....  Column AC (unique ID)
    DEF          111               ABC
    DEF          222               DEF
    DEF          111               GHI
    ABC          444               JKL
    DEF          333
    DEF          111
    ABC          444
    ABC          555
    JKL          666
    JKL          666
    GHI          777
    GHI          888
    ABC          555

   Desired Output:
    Column B     Column C   ....  Column AC  Column AD (unique values comma separated)
    DEF          111               ABC       444,555
    DEF          222               DEF       111,222,333
    DEF          111               GHI       777,888
    DEF          333               JKL       666,999
    DEF          111
    ABC          444
    ABC          555
    JKL          666
    JKL          666
    JKL          999
    GHI          777
    GHI          888
    ABC          555
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a Excel UDF (User Defined Function) for this.

Set it up like this:

```
Public Function mylookup(inputrange As Range, match As Range) As String
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim d As Object
Dim result As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim v As Variant
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr() = inputrange.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = match Then
        d(arr(i, 2)) = 1
    End If
Next i
For Each v In d.Keys()
        result = result & v & ","
Next v
    result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)

mylookup = result

End Function
```

From there, just use it like a formula. The first argument is the full list of values and the second argument is the specific value you're wanting to do a lookup on.

```
=mylookup(B1:B90,AC1)
```

EDIT: 
I missed one of your original requirements, to filter out duplicate values. I added a dictionary object to do that.

Comment: BryanC - Your solution works, except it does not eliminate duplicates. For example, using my sample data, the UDF you suggested returns the following results when looking up unique ID=ABC: 444,444,555,555  However, I am looking to eliminate the duplicates so that the result when looking up unique ID ABC would be = 444,555

Comment: @Qorn sorry about that. fixed now.

Comment: BryanC- Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! Hats off to you for coming to the rescue.